# Label Focus Color Change in s:label

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I want to change the text color of the S:Label control on rollover by changing the style i want to change the text color to different. can any one please help me. For example i mouse over on Label the text of the color should change to green but not background color.

Answer (score 0):

In actionscript add a mouse over listener and mouse out listener to the label. In the function for mouse over just put in:

```
label.setStyle("color","#00FF00");
```

and on the mouse out revert it back to #000000 for black.

Note: In actionscript color normally refers to text color and you get a seperate variable for the background normally used as backgroundColor.